# Why can't new[] {AnonymousType, AnonymousType} be casted to IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have an array of an anonymous type declared as:

```
var list = new[] 
{
    new {Name = "A", Age = 10},
    new {Name = "B", Age = 15}
}
```

Now list inherits from type Array, which implements IEnumerable. Why does the following fail:

```
Convert.ChangeType(list, typeof(IEnumerable));
```

This also fails:

```
Convert.ChangeType(list, typeof(Array));
```

Kind regards,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Convert.ChangeType` method requires an implementation of `IConvertible` - essentially a declaration of how to convert from the source type to the target type.  `System.Array` does not implement the `IConvertible` interface.

What you are trying to do is cast from one type to another, and `(IEnumerable)list` works perfectly well.

Edit:

As Jon says, the cast here is implicit, so simple assignment (ie implicit cast) to an IEnumerable also works.

Comment: You don't even need a cast - the conversion is implicit.

Comment: True.  Leaving the explicit cast example is just to point out how to do a cast, if that's what the op is trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the implicit conversion and it's fine:

```
IEnumerable enumerable = list;
```

As Nader says, `Convert.ChangeType` works with `IConvertible`. Personally I can't remember the last time I used it - I would stick with simple casts etc where possible.